# Diagnostic Live CD

Tags: live-cd, automated-testing

I'm looking for an automated diagnostic live cd/usb drive for testing all hardware independent of the operating system.

I'm also looking for an automated anti-virus/anti-spyware live cd/usb drive that updates if there is a network available.

And when I say automated, I mean no interaction needed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of any completely automated products but for stress testing/benchmarking there is:

http://www.inquisitor.ru/download.html

And as for virus scanning there is UBCD4Win which has several virus scanners on it that can be updated at the time of build and you just build a new one when you need to use it.

http://www.ubcd4win.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go to your vendor. Dell has a hardware diagnostic cd for dell hardware. As for a more generally applicable suite of applications, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm also looking for an automated
>   anti-virus/anti-spyware live cd/usb
>   drive that updates if there is a
>   network available.

You can remaster a Linux Live CD to include antivirus-software. Then updating the virus definitions, mounting all drives and running the scan can be done by a simple shell script that runs after boot.

I've done something similar with Sophos a while ago. The only problem I've had so far was when the update-engine on the live system got too old to connect to the update server and I had build a new image.